# Scrapy : Can't get hidden data from page with FormRequest

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have been trying to scrape [this page](https://www.topachat.com/pages/lexique2_marque_est_APPLE_puis_cat_est_accueil.html).

I can't seem to get the "load more results" ("voir plus de résultats" in french) to load in my response object.

When I scrape, I usually use the network monitoring trick to check the `AJAX` requests, but there is no activity shown when I do click on "load more results". That's why I'm assuming the results are already loaded but hidden.

Here's my code so far, which returns a there is `no clickable element matching clickdata {'href' :"#"}`.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from TopAchat.items import TopachatItem

class TopAchatSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "TopAchat1"
    start_urls = ["https://www.topachat.com/pages/marque.php"]

    rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="content"]/section/ul[@class="listProduct"]//a'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//li[@class='link-visible']//a","//li[@class='display: list-item']//a")),callback='parse_item'),
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):

        item = TopachatItem()
        item["brandname"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='small']/div/text()").extract_first()[4:].split(" ")[0]
        item["href"] = response.request.url 
        item["name"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='libelle']/h1/text()").extract_first()
        item["specs"] = response.xpath("//strong[@class='big short-descr']/text()").extract_first()
        item["product_type"] = response.xpath("//nav[@class='meta small']//p//b/text()").extract_first()

        return item,scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            clickdata = {'href' :"#"})
```

I know there are other ways to scrape the data (`Selenium` namely), but it feels like I'm missing something obvious, and I can't seem to find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have this in HTML source:

```
                <li class='link-visible'>                                   <a href='/pages/detail2_cat_est_ordinateurs_puis_rubrique_est_wh_tabmul_puis_ref_est_in10092521.html'>
                                apple ipad mini 4 7.9'' retina 128 go wi-fi gris sideral (2015)                                     &nbsp;<strong>(MK9N2NF/A</strong>)                                  </a>
                        </li>
                    <li class='link-visible'>                                   <a href='/pages/detail2_cat_est_ordinateurs_puis_rubrique_est_wh_tabmul_puis_ref_est_in10103554.html'>
                                Apple iPad 32 Go Wi-Fi Or (2017)                                        &nbsp;<strong>(MPGT2NF/A</strong>)                                  </a>
                        </li>
                    <li>                                    <a href='/pages/detail2_cat_est_ordinateurs_puis_rubrique_est_wh_tabmul_puis_ref_est_in10103538.html'>
                                apple ipad 32 go wi-fi gris sideral (2017)                                      &nbsp;<strong>(MP2F2NF/A</strong>)                                  </a>
                        </li>
                    <li>                                    <a href='/pages/detail2_cat_est_ordinateurs_puis_rubrique_est_wh_tabmul_puis_ref_est_in10103545.html'>
                                Apple iPad 32 Go Wi-Fi Silver (2017)                                        &nbsp;<strong>(MP2G2NF/A</strong>)                                  </a>
                        </li>
```

So as you can see it's `//li[@class="link-visible"]/a` (you have this) and `//li/a` (you need to add this to catch "load more results")

Comment: Didn't see that I was self restricting myself, thank you !